# Help to align equations

Tags: equations, align, brackets

I'm trying to write an equation with brackets and I have problems.
I want to align the equations after the brackets. For this I introduce "align" but as far as I know align cannot be inside an equation. That is why for the code below I get the error "trying to recover with `aligned'.":

```
\begin{equation}

\Pi_{b}\ge 1 \quad \text{for}\quad 

\left\lbrace

\begin{align}

& \gamma\le\gamma_0=3-2\sqrt{2}\\

& \gamma\ge 1/\gamma_0=3+2\sqrt{2}

\end{align}\right.

\end{equation}
```

Then, how can I represent the equation without error?

Thank you.
Rubén Picó

Comment: (1) no blank lines in displayed math, (2) Don't use `align` inside `equation`, ought to be `aligned` instead, but here there is an even better solutiuon `\begin{cases} ... `\end{cases}` automaticallyu adds the `\{` on the left, you can use ` f(x) & \text{for $x>0$} \\ 0 & \text{else}`

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want?

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \Pi_{b}\ge 1 \quad \text{for}\quad
    \left\lbrace
    \begin{aligned}
     \gamma &\le\gamma_0=3-2\sqrt{2}\\
     \gamma &\ge 1/\gamma_0=3+2\sqrt{2}
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dalief's suggestion that the cases environment be used is an excellent one.

Comment: @Charles B. Cameron: I know, but I wanted to modify the original code as little as possible. There's also a possibility with the `empheq` environment and the  `empheqlbrace` command